# if number of results returned > X then hide element angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I would like to detect the amount of results returned in an ng-repeat loop and then if it is more than a certain number, execute code eg. hide an HTML tag. So if p in pics is more than X then hide something. Not sure how to go about it:

Here is a snippet of my code:

**HTML**

```
<li ng-repeat="p in pics">
    <a href="{{p.link}}" target="_blank"><img ng-src="{{p.images.thumbnail.url}}" /></a>
    <p>{{p.comments.data|getFirstCommentFrom:'alx_lloyd'}}</p>
</li>
```

**JS**

```
(function(){
    //Place your own Instagram client_id below. Go to https://instagram.com/developer/clients/manage/ and register your app to get a client ID
  var client_id = ''; //redacted
    //To get your user ID go to http://jelled.com/instagram/lookup-user-id and enter your Instagram user name to get your user ID
  var user_id = ''; //redacted

  var app = angular.module('instafeed', ['ngAnimate']);
  app.filter('getFirstCommentFrom',function() {
      return function(arr, user) {
          for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
             if(arr[i].from.username==user)
                 return arr[i].text;
          }
          return '';
      }
  })

  app.factory("InstagramAPI", ['$http', function($http) {
    return {
      fetchPhotos: function(callback){
        var endpoint = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/liked/";
        endpoint += "?access_token=foobar";
        endpoint += "&callback=JSON_CALLBACK";
        /*   var endpoint = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/" + user_id + "/media/recent/?";
        endpoint += "?count=99";
        endpoint += "&client_id=" + client_id;
        endpoint += "&callback=JSON_CALLBACK";
*/
        $http.jsonp(endpoint).success(function(response){
          callback(response.data);

        });
      }
    }
  }]);

  app.controller('ShowImages', function($scope, InstagramAPI){
    $scope.layout = 'grid';
    $scope.data = {};
    $scope.pics = [];



    InstagramAPI.fetchPhotos(function(data){
      $scope.pics = data;
      console.log(data)
    });
  });


})();
```

Comment: So do you only want to show the first few and hide the rest, or hide them all if there are more than some number (so none show at all)?

Comment: Hide the div container of the grid if the there more than 6 for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ng-hide since your pics are just in an array and check the length of the array, e.g:

```
  <h2 ng-hide="pics.length > 5">HIDE ME</h2>
```

---

```js
(function() {
  //Place your own Instagram client_id below. Go to https://instagram.com/developer/clients/manage/ and register your app to get a client ID
  var client_id = '83aaab0bddea42adb694b689ad169fb1';
  //To get your user ID go to http://jelled.com/instagram/lookup-user-id and enter your Instagram user name to get your user ID
  var user_id = '179735937';

  var app = angular.module('instafeed', ['ngAnimate']);
  
  app.filter('getFirstCommentFrom', function() {
    return function(arr, user) {
      for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i].from.username == user)
          return arr[i].text;
      }
      return '';
    }
  })

  app.factory("InstagramAPI", ['$http',
    function($http) {
      return {
        fetchPhotos: function(callback) {
          var endpoint = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/liked/";
          endpoint += "?access_token=179735937.83aaab0.e44fe9abccb5415290bfc0765edd45ad";
          endpoint += "&callback=JSON_CALLBACK";
          $http.jsonp(endpoint).success(function(response) {
            callback(response.data);
          });
        }
      }
    }
  ]);

  app.controller('ShowImages', function($scope, InstagramAPI) {
    $scope.layout = 'grid';
    $scope.data = {};
    $scope.pics = [];

    InstagramAPI.fetchPhotos(function(data) {
      $scope.pics = data;
      console.log(data)
    });
  });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-animate.js"></script>

<div ng-app='instafeed' ng-controller='ShowImages'>
  <li ng-repeat="p in pics">
    <a href="{{p.link}}" target="_blank">
      <img ng-src="{{p.images.thumbnail.url}}" />
    </a>
    <p>{{p.comments.data|getFirstCommentFrom:'alx_lloyd'}}</p>
  </li>
  <h2 ng-hide="pics.length > 5">HIDE ME</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want mean is something like "show only the first four results" then you can do this by using `$index` from the ng-repeat.

For instance the following will show items with 0 <= $index <= 3.

```
<li ng-repeat="p in pics" ng-if="$index < 4">
```

You can reference `$index` anywhere inside the repeat - not just on the repeat itself:

```
<li ng-repeat="p in pics">
    <a href="{{p.link}}" target="_blank"><img ng-src="{{p.images.thumbnail.url}}" /></a>

    <p ng-if="$index<4">{{p.comments.data|getFirstCommentFrom:'alx_lloyd'}}</p>
</li>
```

Alternatively if you want to hide the whole lot then you should be able to take the length from the array:

```
<div id="container" ng-if="pics.length <= 4">
    <li ng-repeat="p in pics">
    ...
    </li>
</div>
```

For any of these you can choose between `ng-if` and `ng-hide`. I would tend to prefer ng-if, as it causes the render to be ignored completely. `ng-hide` will render all the markup, and then just set to `display:none;`, which is more likely to be useful where the condition can change due to the user's input to the page (for example).

As @DTing points out, you can also use a filter on the repeat itself if you want to apply the filter at that level:

```
<li ng-repeat="p in pics | limitTo: 4">
```

Comment: great thanks, but how can I execute code like a hide a div container if there are more 3 for example.

Comment: I could imagine something like `ng-hide="pics.length > 3"` on the div you want to hide would work

Comment: You can use the limitTo filter: `<lg ng-repeat="p in pics | limitTo: 50">`

Comment: @DTing: That's a nice idea too - angular has so may ways to skin a cat.

Comment: hi, thing is that ng-hide has to be within the loop I guess right? Because I'd want to hide an outer container.

Comment: If the container is outside the `ng-repeat` you're going to need to move the `ng-repeat` out to that container.